# AsyncTask and IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, android-asynctask, mqtt

in the app I am developing, when I touch the screen of the device, I connect to a server and i show a busy indicator using AsyncTask, and at this step i have no
problem. but while i am connected and press the home buttom "the App goes into onPause" and i bring the App to be visible again "onResume" and touch the screen 
to connect to the server again, I receive the below posted logCat errors.

to note: in onPause I urnRegister the WiFi receiver and I disconnect from the server. and the logCat output shows the sequence of the invoked callbacks of the AsyncTask

I do not know why I am receiving IllegalArgumentException, i read some postes about it and I tested the object that is called "client", and it is never null

**LogCat**:

```
03-09 14:26:13.413: D/MainActivity(17065): @MQTTAsynchTask(): constructor called
03-09 14:26:13.413: D/MainActivity(17065): @MQTTAsynchTask(): client is not null
03-09 14:26:13.413: D/MainActivity(17065): @MQTTAsynchTask(): onPreExecute().
03-09 14:26:13.422: D/MainActivity(17065): @MQTTAsynchTask(): doInBackground().
03-09 14:26:13.433: E/AndroidRuntime(17065): FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-1-thread-1
03-09 14:26:13.433: E/AndroidRuntime(17065): Process: com.example.mqtt_designlayout_02, PID: 17065
03-09 14:26:13.433: E/AndroidRuntime(17065): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid ClientHandle
03-09 14:26:13.433: E/AndroidRuntime(17065):    at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService.getConnection(MqttService.java:552)
03-09 14:26:13.433: E/AndroidRuntime(17065):    at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService.connect(MqttService.java:318)
03-09 14:26:13.433: E/AndroidRuntime(17065):    at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient.doConnect(MqttAndroidClient.java:427)
03-09 14:26:13.433: E/AndroidRuntime(17065):    at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient.access$2(MqttAndroidClient.java:417)
03-09 14:26:13.433: E/AndroidRuntime(17065):    at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient$1.run(MqttAndroidClient.java:395)
03-09 14:26:13.433: E/AndroidRuntime(17065):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-09 14:26:13.433: E/AndroidRuntime(17065):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-09 14:26:13.433: E/AndroidRuntime(17065):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**AsynchTask**

```
public MQTTAsynchTask(Context contex, MqttAndroidClient client, MqttConnectOptions opts) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        Log.d(TAG, "@MQTTAsynchTask(): constructor called");
        this.context = contex;
        this.MQTTAndroidClient = client;
        if (client != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "@MQTTAsynchTask(): client is not null");
        }
        this.opts = opts;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.d(TAG, "@MQTTAsynchTask(): onPreExecute().");

        dialog = new Dialog(this.context);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressdialog);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG, "@MQTTAsynchTask(): doInBackground().");
        do {
            try {
                this.MQTTAndroidClient.connect(this.opts, this.context, synchCONNCallBack);
            } catch (MqttSecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MqttException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(MQTT_BROKER_TIME_OUT);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            this.totalTimeOut += MQTT_BROKER_TIME_OUT;

        } while ( (!this.isCancelled()) && (this.MQTTAndroidClient != null) && (!this.MQTTAndroidClient.isConnected()) && (this.totalTimeOut <= (10 * MQTT_BROKER_TIME_OUT)) );

        return null;
    }
```

**onPause**:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    Log.w(TAG, "@onPause()");

    this.onPauseCalled = true;

    if (reconnectTimerCurrentlyActive) {
        reconnectTimerCurrentlyActive = false;
        reconnectTimer.cancel();
        reconnectTimer.purge();
        Log.v(TAG, "reconnect timer set to 'false', and reconnectTimer is cancelled");
    }

    if (this.MQTTAsynch != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "asynchTask object was initilised");
        if (this.MQTTAsynch.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.PENDING) {
            Log.d(TAG, "AsynchTask has not started yet.");
            boolean cancelledSuccessully = this.MQTTAsynch.cancel(true);
            if (cancelledSuccessully) {
                Log.d(TAG, "AsynchTask is cancelled successfully.");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "AsynchTask failed to cancell");
            }
        }
        if (this.MQTTAsynch.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
            Log.d(TAG, "AsynchTask still running doing work in the backgroung thread, and it will be intrrupted");
            boolean cancelledSuccessully = this.MQTTAsynch.cancel(true);
            if (cancelledSuccessully) {
                Log.d(TAG, "AsynchTask is cancelled successfully.");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "AsynchTask failed to cancell");
            }
        }
        if (this.MQTTAsynch.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
            Log.d(TAG, "AsynchTask has finished its work.");
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "asynchTask object was not initilised. this.MQTTAsynch == null");
    }

    if ( (this.subActivityReturned) || (this.isConnectCalled) ) {
        MQTT_Disconnect_Module();
    }

    if (MQTTPrimaryReceiverRegistered) {
        unregisterReceiver(MQTTPrimaryReceiver);
        Log.v(TAG, "BroadCastReceiver (MQTTPrimaryReceiver) unregistered");
        MQTTPrimaryReceiverRegistered = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: The problem is not your Client nor a NullPointerException (client being null), the error begins in this class: MqttService, on line 552, and continues on MqttAndroidClient. I suggest you check them out

Comment: @rmaik. Am also facing the same issue, did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 10):

I think the first thing to learn from this is to read ErrorLogs completely and understand it. The first line of the **stacktrace** says that

```
03-09 14:26:13.433: E/AndroidRuntime(17065): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid ClientHandle
03-09 14:26:13.433: E/AndroidRuntime(17065):    at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService.getConnection(MqttService.java:552)
```

i.e the error starts in `MqttService` class in the method `getConnection()`. The method `getConnection()` is throwing `IllegalArgumentException` and not the `AsyncTask`. It just happens to be called from inside `AsyncTask`. Also the variable **ClientHandle** is not part of Android API, it is part of your `MqttService`. This variable is actually invalid and is leading to the exception.

You can also share your `MqttService` class if you cannot figure out why the variable `ClientHandle` is Invalid. Maybe people here can assist you on that, but with the information provided this is what I can answer. Hope this helps.